# How can I access a specific OnGet function of a RazorPage from javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I've got a razor page with 3 `OnGet` functions but no matter how I try to call it, it always goes to the original `OnGet` function.

```
public class MyRazorPageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ISessionProvider ISP = null;

    public MyRazorPageModel(ISessionProvider iSessionProvider)
    {
        ISP = iSessionProvider;
    }

    public void OnGet(int employeeId)
    {
        //All requests come here for some reason

        //Load logic
    }

    public void OnGetNextEmployee(int employeeId)
    {
        int index = ISP.EmployeeIds.FindIndex(id => id == employeeId);

        if(index == -1) //Not found
        {
            OnGet(employeeId);
        }
        else if(index == ISP.EmployeeIds.Count - 1) //End of list
        {
            OnGet(employeeId);
        }
        else
        {
            int nextEmployeeId = ISP.EmployeeIds[index + 1];
            OnGet(nextEmployeeId);
        }
    }

    public void OnGetPreviousEmployee(int employeeId)
    {
        int index = ISP.EmployeeIds.FindIndex(id => id == employeeId);

        if (index == -1) //Not found
        {
            OnGet(employeeId);
        }
        else if (index == 0) //Start of list
        {
            OnGet(employeeId);
        }
        else
        {
            int previousEmployeeId = ISP.EmployeeIds[index - 1];
            OnGet(previousEmployeeId);
        }
    }
}
```

In javascript I have:

```
var wnd = window.parent.$("#DetailWnd").data("kendoWindow");
var _url = "/MyRazorPage?handler=NextEmployee?employeeId=" + $('#EmployeeId').val();
wnd.refresh({
    url: _url
});
```

But it only ever goes to `OnGet`, never `OnGetNextEmployee` or `OnGetPreviousEmployee`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `_url` has two instances of `?` in the query string. The second instance needs to be changed to `&`.

Original:

```
var _url = "/MyRazorPage?handler=NextEmployee?employeeId=" + $('#EmployeeId').val();
```

Replacing the second `?` at `...NextEmployee?employeeId...` will fix the routing to the correct `OnGet` handler.

```
var _url = "/MyRazorPage?handler=NextEmployee&employeeId=" + $('#EmployeeId').val();
```